# Using alternative (translated) titles in dynamic menus in Lektor

Tags: python-3.6, lektor

I'm new to Lektor and I've been using this snippet in my layout to dynamically generate menus

```
{% for content in site.get('/').children %}
    <li><a href="{{ content|url(alt=alt) }}">{{ content.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

It works fine to produce the `alt` url accordingly to the alternative (language) selected, but the `title` is still shown only in the primary language of the content instead of the translated one.

That means that when a say french `alt` is selected (and present in the url), menus are still i.e. `Main`, `Contact` instead of the french translated version.

I know I can work around this using a databag to hold a language mapping for the menus, but that would require to duplicate the title information in the databag and then make sure it stays in sync with whatever is in `content.title`.

Ideally what I'm missing is a filter for `title` where you can specify the `alt` you want to use, or some other method that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naive as it may be, I didn't realize that you can pass the `alt` parameter in `site.get` until after I looked at the source code. So the way to get the defined child pages for a certain language is:

```
{% for content in site.get('/', alt=alt).children %}
    <li><a href="{{ content }}">{{ content.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

And since we already specified the `alt` parameter in the get, we don't need to filter the `url` anymore for the current alt.